# Обновить массив

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте.

У нас есть массив:

```
$arr = array(0 => 'test1', 1 => 'test2', 2 => 'test3');
```

Мы выполняем функцию:

```
unset($arr[1]);
```

На выходе получаем:

```
array(0 => 'test1', 2 => 'test3');
```

Как получить такой вариант:

```
array(0 => 'test1', 1 => 'test3');
```

?

Comment: @nick777 - а почему нумерация массива с единицы?.. Зачем?

Comment: чуть ошибся, нумерация с нуля

Comment: Тогда http://codepad.org/DcP5iaVn

Comment: >Замечание:  
>  
>Функция unset() позволяет удалять ключи массива. Обратите внимание, что массив НЕ будет переиндексирован. Если вы действительно хотите поведения в стиле "удалить и сдвинуть", можно переиндексировать массив используя array_values().

[Источник]( http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```
$arr[2] = $arr[3]; unset($arr[3]);
```

Если нужно более общее решение, то надо уточнять условия.

Answer (score 4):

[array_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php) — Выбирает все значения массива. В PHP возвращает индексированный массив значений.

В вашем примере после `unset($arr[1])`, сделайте

```
$arr= array_values($arr); //переиндексация
```

и получите нумерацию ключей по возрастанию